# Using .click to increase numeral digits statement in javascript

Tags: javascript

I've been working on this website since the beginning of summer and wanted to finish before it ends.
So, my friend recently explained to me that 'Javascript' can remove the 'divs' from 'block' to 'none'. So, I did that.

Anyways, I tried to find some way to increase count or 'i++'. So, let's say I wanted. If I click on this div once it will increase the width and hide all the other div's(4 div's in total). If I click it once more it would bring the other div's back and it would bring this div original size and reset the 'I' to zero. Thanks!

```
function handlerForFirstDiv() {

  var i = 0;
!
    i++;
    if (i = 2) {
        a.style.width = "150%";
        a.style.transform = "translate(-2.5vw, -2vh)";
        b.style.position = "relative";
        c.style.display = "none";
        d.style.width = "10vw";
    }
    else {
        d.style.width = "50vw";
    }
!
}
```

Comment: I have hard time understanding why there are 7 elements with same `id`. Also please, edit question with better formating and it would be super nice to have minimal working snippet instead of one function.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to make an Accordian. You can get complete and easy guide here. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp